# How to use hooks for overriding homepage content in cs cart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I am new to cs-cart and I am trying to use hooks in cs-cart. 
I had gone through some cs-cart website but not getting proper answer.
I want to override homepage content but not the banner with new content then how can i do it using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Homepage doesn't have any content at all, there are only blocks that can be managed from **Homepage** layout:

## 1

[image]

## 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More details about the hooks can be found in the following documentation:

http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/addons/hooking/tpl_hooks.html

Here are also several articles where you can learn how to use blocks to customize your Home page in the required way:

http://kb.cs-cart.com/blocks

http://www.cs-cart.com/documentation/reference_guide/index.htmld?design_block_manager_blocks.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all blocks in layout > homepage then everything will be removed except for block which are in Default.

If you want to override homepage data then remove all blocks in homepage layout and add you own block.

See image below for more clear picture how to add your own block.

[image]

Please note you cannot override homepage but you can modify according to you.